# Single Phase Induction Motor Working Principle

Tags: motor, ac, induction-motor

It is often said that the main stator winding of a single phase induction motor provides zero torque, if so what is its function? How does it help in keeping the rotor rotating?

How could one using electromagnetic theory, and the geometrical parameters of the motor determine its rotation speed?

Why does the motor yield zero torque at a maximum rotation speed? What causes the back-reaction? I am guessing this is due to the dissipative impedance in the windings, correct?

Comment: This helps but I need more info on other details as well. Thank you very much for the link though!

Comment: You are going to have to clarify **I need more info on other details as well** because your question is on the path to be closed.

Comment: Here is another question that might be helpful: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/252307/when-load-increases-in-rotor-of-induction-motor-how-does-stator-draws-more-curre

Comment: @Joseph123; what you said is often said is not true. Where did you get that? What do you mean by back reaction? Where did you find the term "dissociative impedance?

Comment: There is zero torque at maximum (synchronous) speed because there must be a difference between the speed of the rotor conductors and the speed of the rotating stator magnetic field for the stator field to induce current in the rotor conductors.

Comment: See also: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/559819/in-absence-of-leakage-what-creates-the-angle-between-stator-and-rotor-flux-in-a

Comment: @CharlesCowie Could you recommend me a book on single-phase induction motors?

Comment: "It is often said".  *Please* no.  *Cite an actual example*.  It is often said that the Earth is flat -- but the Earth isn't flat.  It is often said that the Moon is made of green cheese -- but, quite boringly, the Moon is made of rock.  If you *cite an example*, then we can weigh in on the credibility of that example.

Comment: @Joseph123; Some leading texts that I know of are: Fitzgerald & Kingsley's Electric Machinery by Stephen Umans; Electric Machinery Fundamentals by Stephen J. Chapman; Introduction to Ac Machine Design by Thomas A. Lipo. I believe they all cover single phase motors. You need to learn about 3-phase motor first. Single-phase motors are actually a bit more difficult to understand than 3-phase motors. If you can't get a book from a library, The least expensive option will probably be to buy an older edition.